Excel Custom RibbonUI + COM visible dll : can I subscribe to ribbon controls events in the dll?
I am developing a COM visible DLL in C#, and this DLL is referenced in an Excel VBA project. The idea is to outsource all the code to the DLL, rather than using VBA. The VBA is only used to subscribe to the different events of my Excel workbook:
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  With New ProjectXLib.EndPoint
    Call .Subscribe(Excel.ThisWorkbook)
  End With
End Sub

Here is my IEndPoint interface:
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ProjectXLib.Source
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [Guid("6ca9d5e5-41fe-45f3-8ccb-8106288a447c")]
    public interface IEndPoint
    {
        void Subscribe(Excel.Workbook workbook);
    }
}

Here is the implementation of IEndPoint:
using ExcelCoreLib.Source.Core;
using ProjectXLib.Source.Events;
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ProjectXLib.Source
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [Guid("e8b3885e-8ea3-4bcb-baa2-b5b7b1e9f8f3")]
    [ProgId(nameof(EndPoint))]
    public class EndPoint : IEndPoint
    {
        public EndPoint() { }

        public void Subscribe(Excel.Workbook workbook)
        {
            using (Macro.GetInstance(workbook.Application))
            {
                WorkbookEvents.Subscribe(workbook);
            }
        }
    }
}

It is in the WorkbookEvents class that I subscribe to my workbook events and ActiveX controls to code:
using ExcelCoreLib.Source.Core;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using MSForms = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms;

namespace ProjectXLib.Source.Events
{
    internal static class WorkbookEvents
    {
        private static Excel.Workbook Workbook { get; set; }
        private static Excel.WorkbookEvents_Event Events { get; set; }
        private static MSForms.CommandButton BtnErrors { get; set; }

        public static void Subscribe(Excel.Workbook workbook)
        {
            Workbook = workbook;
            Events = workbook;

            // Buttons
            BtnErrors = Worksheet.GetCommandButton(workbook.Worksheets["Errors"], "btnErrors");
            BtnErrors.Click += BtnErrors_Click;

            // Events
            Events.BeforeClose += Workbook_BeforeClose;
            Events.SheetBeforeDoubleClick += Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick;
            Events.SheetChange += Workbook_SheetChange;
            Events.AfterSave += Workbook_AfterSave;
        }

        private static void BtnErrors_Click()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world from dll!");
        }

        private static void Workbook_BeforeClose(ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Events.BeforeClose -= Workbook_BeforeClose;
            Events.SheetBeforeDoubleClick -= Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick;
            Events.SheetChange -= Workbook_SheetChange;
            Events.AfterSave -= Workbook_AfterSave;
            BtnErrors.Click -= BtnErrors_Click;
        }

        private static void Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(object Sh, Excel.Range Target, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            if (Target.Count.Equals(1) && Target.Value2 is bool && !Target.HasFormula)
            {
                Cancel = true; Target.Value2 = !Target.Value2;
            }
        }

        private static void Workbook_SheetChange(object Sh, Excel.Range Target)
        {
            Worksheet.CastAs(Sh).CircleInvalid();
        }

        private static void Workbook_AfterSave(bool Success)
        {
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = Workbook.ActiveSheet;
            worksheet.CircleInvalid();
        }
    }
}

All of this works fine. I register my DLL with Regasm, reference it within the Excel workbook, events and buttons events work fine. My problem is that I can't subscribe buttons from my CustomRibbonUI:
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="idMacros" label="Macros">
        <group id="idErrors" label="Errors">
          <button id="btnReset" label="Reset" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large"/>
          <button id="btnFindInvalidCells" label="Invalid cells" imageMso="HappyFace" size="large"/>
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>

I searched a lot before writing to you. Ideally, I don't want to make any additional implementation in VBA, except for a RibbonOnLoad method when loading the ribbon, in the same way that I use the Workbook_Open event to subscribe to workbook events when opening the workbook. I would like to subscribe my btnReset and btnFindInvalidCells buttons to Click-related events, for example, and have the implementation of these events done in the DLL.
Among other things, I tried adding and implementing IRibbonExtensibility interface without success, maybe I did it wrong.
Thank you to those who have read this far and to those who will help me.

Why do you even want to subscribe to specific button presses? (What are the reasons you are set on doing it this way?) Because from what I understand this would couple the implementation in your DLL to your custom ribbon implementation.
<button id="btnFindInvalidCells" [...] onAction="handleInvalidCells"/>

Sub handleInvlaidCells(control As IRibbonControl)
    'call DLL function here
End Sub

This way bot the ribbon menu and the code in your DLL can change independently without requiring a change in the other

I'm not certain I understand your question (I'm french). Aren't buttons precisely specific to a purpose ? So would be their implementation. My goal is to avoid unnecessary VBA code maintenance in the workbook. If I need a new button, I add it in my workbook, I change the name, and I'm able to manage its events in the dll directly (as shown in the WorkbookEvents class) without adding any VBA code. I'm trying to mimic this behavior for the ribbon.
